# Comparing nonlinear models using the Chi-squared asymptotic approximation

Tags: chi-squared-test, nonlinear-regression, approximation

I am attempting to identify the best model fit for a nonlinear mixed effects model using the asymptotic approximation to the Chi-squared test. When calculating the appropriate number of degrees of freedom should it be based on the number of parameters included in the model, or the number of ways that I can express those parameters?

For example, I am evaluating the fit of the model using the three formulations below, where Theta denotes fixed effects and Eta denotes random effects:

```
Result = (Theta(1) * Covariate)^Eta(1)
Result = (Theta(1) * (Covariate / Covariate Mean))^Eta(1)
Result = (Theta(1) * (Covariate)^Theta(2))^Eta(1)
```

My question is whether it is fair to compare the fit of these alternative models based on the Chi-squared statistic (with a single degree of freedom?) or should the model fit be guided by other diagnostics (e.g., residuals and prediction errors)?

Comment: (I love seeing "asymptomatic" appear on our site.  It is a medical term for "showing no signs of problems."  Presumably you mean "asymptotic.") Could you elaborate on the distinction between the "number of parameters" and "the number of ways [to] express" them?

Comment: Oops -- sorry about that.  You are absolutely right and I have updated it to read 'asymptotic'.  As for the distinction between the 'number of parameters' and the 'number of ways to express them' I really mean the differences between Example 1 and 2 above, where the covariate is still used but it is expressed differently in the 2nd example since it is normalized by the mean value.  For assessing the difference in fit between these two models, is it fair to use a decrease in the AIC/BIC or should I rely upon other diagnostics?